# SSRS, Report Builder, Report Viewer Win Forms

Tags: c#, reportviewer, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

i'm afraid i can't explain exactly my problem.
i configured my ssrs server successfully, i did every thing either at home network (adsl connection) or at work network (adsl connection) and also with usb modem for some service provider lets call it provider1 until this moment every thing is going great.
One day i changed the service provider for my usb modem lets call it provider2, while i'm connecting throw this provider report viewer can't load the report ending with 401 unauthorized, also when i try to open a report on the report builder it asks for credentials and it refuses my credentials that i configured the server on.

Answer (score 0):

Its really difficult to tell what your problem is, but I'll give it a go.

You say SSRS is prompting you for credentials ? but only when connecting through Provider2 ? If so, then I guess you've set up your SSRS for Windows integrated (NTLM) credentials and Provider2 is not forwarding your Windows credentials (this is normal - Windows Credentials really aren't designed for multi-hop scenarious like public internet providers).

I would convert your SSRS to use SQL Server logins and it should then work in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but may you tell me how can i convert to use sql server logins ?

Comment: i changed the database credentials to sql server user / password, i cofigured the service account as network service, report service, domain/user and nothing changed :(